# Need to run Jtest by using an ant script...any example?

Tags: ant, parasoft, jtest

Need to run Jtest by using an ant script...any example ?

I have done this so far

```
<target name="test">

 <jtest config="/Carts Static Analysis.properties" localsettings="/ApplicationCore.jtest/scripts/build.properties"
        publish="false" showdetails="false" nobuild="true"
        report="c:/reports" workspace="C:/"> 

        <resource name="EC"/> 

 </jtest>
</target>
</project>
```

But I get an error that "Failed to create task or type jtest. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Could you describe your environment/context in more detail. How are you invoking ant? e.g. from an IDE like Eclipse?

Comment: @DariusX I am invoking ant using command line. I am still testing the file to make sure that it runs the Jtest and generate report so the method of invoking ant doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check Parasoft web page :
http://build.parasoft.com/docs/overview.html ?